# Simplifying recursive updating of records

Tags: elm

Can this code be simplified?

```
update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  let
    formValue = model.formValue
  in
    case action of
      UpdateWhat what ->
        let
          newValue = { formValue | what <- what }
        in
          { model | formValue <- newValue }
      UpdateTrigger trigger ->
        let
          newValue = { formValue | trigger <- trigger }
        in
          { model | formValue <- newValue }
```

As I plan to add a couple more of `Update...` clauses, it is helpful to abstract this out a bit.

The code is written the way it is because Elm does not accept inner record updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [focus library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/focus/latest):

> ## Focus
>
> A Focus is a way to work with particular parts of a large chunk of data. On the most basic level, it lets you get and set fields of a record in a simple and composable way. This means you could avoid writing special record update syntax and use something that composes much more elegantly.
>
> It gives you the ability to write stuff like freeze in the following snippet:
>
> ```
> mario =
>     { super = False
>     , fire  = False
>     , physics = { position = { x=3, y=4 }
>                 , velocity = { x=1, y=1 }
>                 }
>     }
>
> freeze object =
>     set (physics => velocity) { x=0, y=0 } object
> ```

In the code example physics and velocity are Foci. You can create a focus with code like the following, to use your example:

```
formValue = Focus.create .formValue (\f r -> { r | formValue <- f r.formValue })
what      = Focus.create .what      (\f r -> { r | what      <- f r.what })
trigger   = Focus.create .trigger   (\f r -> { r | trigger   <- f r.trigger })

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    UpdateWhat w -> Focus.set (formValue => what) w model
    UpdateTrigger t -> Focus.set (formValue => trigger) t model
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked: https://github.com/srid/chronicle/commit/c0577c04c330021141a6c544728d5bfd884e094a